# Practical information to prepare a visit to Kakslauttanen (igloo village) in Finland

Tags: hotels, finland, snow

I am planning to visit this Igloo Village([kakslauttanen](http://www.kakslauttanen.fi)). What are the best times to visit and how to go about planning the trip for the same?

A lot of information I found from here - http://seattlestravels.com/spending-the-night-in-an-igloo-in-finnish-lapland/. But, I kind of need more.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  It's not very clear what you're asking here, can you try to narrow this down?

Comment: What do you mean by "best times" - are you asking time of day, time of year, what? Also, what is "best"? what are you looking to get out of the experience?